# How to edit a .bat file in the Winrar window explorer?

Tags: winrar

Has Winrar another way to edit bat file directly in explorer?

I click in a zip file it's show me a Winrar popup with many files, double click in some file open it in default program (.txt in Notepad++, .sql in Toad, etc.), but double click in bat files run the bat. 
Alt + v  is a shortcut to view file, but it does not allow me to edit the bat file.

The only way is drag the file to Windows, edit and drag back to Windows.

Comment: Open zip file... double click bat file... Are you trying to send viruses? The usual way is to extract -> edit -> compress. This is also what happens in explorer, windows extracts the files to a temporary folder then.

Comment: No. My problem is because I have a Wildfly as zip file and I shared with my brother in a personal project, but whenever I need to change the standalone.conf.bat I have to drag the standalone.conf.bat to Windows, open with Notepad++ and drag to Winrar.

Another files I can edit directly, double click open it in Notepad++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*WinRAR* has the feature to temporarily extract a double clicked file to *Folder for temporary files* as defined on tab **Paths** in **Settings** opened from menu **Options**, then start the application associated with that file, and after started application terminated, repack the file if modified at all back into the archive.

That is also done for executable files except the option *File types to exclude from extracting* on tab **Security** is enabled in **Settings** opened from menu **Options** with extracting by default the entire archive as defined under *Unpack everything for* on tab **Viewer** of **Settings**.

But the default behavior on double click can be customized on tab **Viewer** of **Settings**. After selecting there *Ask* instead of *Internal viewer* for *Viewer type* and entering `C:\Windows\Notepad.exe` as *External viewer name* a double click on a *.bat file inside an archive results in prompting the user for viewing with internal or external viewer or opening the file with associated program. Of course `*.bat` should not be in list of setting *Unpack everything for*.

By clicking now on button *External viewer (Notepad.exe)* the batch file is extracted to *Folder for temporary files*, then *Notepad* is started with that file for viewing and for editing. When finishing viewing/editing the batch file and exiting *Notepad*, *WinRAR* detects a modification and asks the user if the modified file should be updated in the archive.

There is the button **Help** on each **Settings** dialog. Please make use of it and read in help of *WinRAR*.

If always the same batch file inside an archive file should be edited, I suggest to automate this task as much as possible by using a batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "FileToEdit=Test.bat"
set "PathInArchive="
set "DefaultArchive=C:\Temp\Test.zip"

rem Set a title for the command prompt window and determine name
rem of this batch file with full path for a possible error message.
title Update %FileToEdit%
set "BatchFile=%~f0"

rem Use a standard archive file if none is specified as first parameter.
if "%~1"=="" (
    set "ArchiveFile=%DefaultArchive%"
) else (
    set "ArchiveFile=%~f1"
)

rem Test if the archive file exists at all.
if not exist "%ArchiveFile%" (
    call :ErrorMessage "Archive file %ArchiveFile% does not exist."
    exit /B
)

rem Make sure path in archive ends with a backslash
rem if a path to file in archive is defined at all.
if not "%PathInArchive%" == "" (
    if not "%PathInArchive:~-1%" == "\" (
        set "PathInArchive=%PathInArchive%\"
    )
)

rem Extract the file to edit to directory for temporary files.
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" e -cfg- -ibck -y -- "%ArchiveFile%" "%PathInArchive%%FileToEdit%" "%TEMP%\"
if errorlevel 1 (
    call :ErrorMessage "Failed to extract file %PathInArchive%%FileToEdit%"
    exit /B
)

rem Start Windows Notepad to edit the temporary extracted file.
start "" /wait %windir%\Notepad.exe "%TEMP%\%FileToEdit%"

rem Define the option -ap with path in archive if needed at all.
set "ArchivePath="
if not "%PathInArchive%" == "" set "ArchivePath=-ap"%PathInArchive%""

rem Update the edited file in archive and delete it on success.
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" u %ArchivePath% -cfg- -df -ibck -ep -y -- "%ArchiveFile%" "%TEMP%\%FileToEdit%"
if errorlevel 1 (
    del "%TEMP%\%FileToEdit%" 2>nul
    call :ErrorMessage "Failed to update file %PathInArchive%%FileToEdit%"
    exit /B
)

rem Exit batch processing.
exit /B

rem Subroutine to output an error message.
:ErrorMessage
echo Error detected by:  %BatchFile%
echo On processing file: %ArchiveFile%
echo.
echo Error: %~1
echo.
endlocal
pause
exit /B
```

The values assigned to the variables `FileToEdit`, `PathInArchive` and `DefaultArchive` at top of the batch file should be defined appropriately.

By creating a shortcut (*.lnk) to this batch file in **SendTo** subfolder of folder `%USERPROFILE%` with a suitable name, right clicking on an archive file with the batch file to modify with fixed name and path inside archive and clicking in submenu **Send To** on this shortcut results in extracting the batch file to folder for temporary files, opening Windows *Notepad* for editing and after repacking finally the modified batch file into the archive file.

Open **Help topics** in menu **Help** in *WinRAR* and click on tab **Contents** on item **Command line mode**. The help pages under this contents list item explain the used **Commands** `e` and `u` as well as the used **Switches**.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?`
- `title /?`

Comment: It was very useful
The solution was in "View" tab, in "Visualization type" the correct choose is the "External Visualization"

Sorry about lable, my Winrar is a portuguese version

Answer (score 2):

1. From WinRAR, click *Options* -> *Settings* -> *Viewer*.
2. Activate *Ask*" into *Viewer type*.
3. Paste `%WINDIR%\notepad.exe` or the path of your favourite editor in *External viewer name*.
4. Click *OK*. Done.

Now, when you double click to any non exe file in the archive, a popup lets you choose how to open it:

- Internal
- External (via notepad or your editor)
- Associated program